# ReportEvent: Logged messages run all lines together

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm noticing that when logging a multi-line message using ReportEvent, it drops all line ends and runs the text together. For example, my MC file may have:

```
MessageId=
Severity=Informational
SymbolicName=MSG_TEST_MSG
Language=English
Some text
Another line of text.
Last line of text.
.
```

The message in Event Viewer shows all three lines run together.

If I put `\r\n` sequences in the text in insertion strings, those line ends do show up correctly in the logged message.

Also, if I use `FormatMessageW` to generate the text string of the above message, the line ends are correctly included in the text. They seem to be removed only when posting to Event Viewer.

I have not seen ANY reference to the fact that line ends are being dropped anywhere. Any idea? Is this just the way it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `%n` to force a "hard line break" inside the message.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/message-text-files):

> %n
>
> Generates a hard line break when it occurs at the end of a line. This
> can be used with FormatMessage to ensure that the message fits a
> certain width.

["Why does Format­Message say that %0 terminates the message without a trailing newline? Is it secretly adding newlines?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191025-00/?p=103025) might also be interesting in this context.

Comment: That does work, but when I add %n to the end of a line it does break the line there, but it doesn't remove the soft line end, so the next line starts with a space and indents the text. Better than before, but I don't understand the utility.